# Get the respective tablenames if it matches particular pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I need to list the table names if it finds particular pattern from the below file.

```
CREATE TABLE IMS.ACTIVITY (
        "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
        OWNING_TYPE FOR COLUMN OWNIN00001 VARCHAR(20) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
        OWNING_ID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
        ACTIVITY_TYPE FOR COLUMN ACTIV00001 VARCHAR(50) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
        CAMPAIGN_TYPE FOR COLUMN CAMPA00001 VARCHAR(50) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
        AUTHOR VARCHAR(100) CCSID 37 NOT NULL ,
        COMPLETED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
        "COMMENT" VARCHAR(1000) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
        CUR_LOCN_STATUS FOR COLUMN CUR_L00001 VARCHAR(20) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
        FOLLOWUP_DATE FOR COLUMN FOLLO00001 DATE DEFAULT NULL ,
        FOLLOWUP_EMAIL FOR COLUMN FOLLO00002 VARCHAR(300) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
        CREATETIMESTAMP FOR COLUMN CRTTIME    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL ,
        CONSTRAINT IMS.QSYS_ACTIVITY_00001 PRIMARY KEY( "ID" ) )
        ;

CREATE TABLE IMS.ADDRESS (
        "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
        PROVINCESTATE FOR COLUMN PROVI00001 VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
        CITY VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
        COUNTRY VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
        ADDRESSLINE1 FOR COLUMN ADDRE00001 VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
        ADDRESSLINE2 FOR COLUMN ADDRE00002 VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
        POSTALCODE VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
        CONSTRAINT IMS.QSYS_ADDRESS_00001 PRIMARY KEY( "ID" ) )
        ;
```

From the above file if we search for `CCSID` It should list the line that contains `CCSID` and the `CREATE TABLE` line for respective `CCSIDs`.

The output should be like

```
CREATE TABLE IMS.ACTIVITY
OWNING_TYPE FOR COLUMN OWNIN00001 VARCHAR(20) CCSID 37 NOT NULL
ACTIVITY_TYPE FOR COLUMN ACTIV00001 VARCHAR(50) CCSID 37 NOT NULL
CAMPAIGN_TYPE FOR COLUMN CAMPA00001 VARCHAR(50) CCSID 37 NOT NULL
AUTHOR VARCHAR(100) CCSID 37 NOT NULL
"COMMENT" VARCHAR(1000) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL
CUR_LOCN_STATUS FOR COLUMN CUR_L00001 VARCHAR(20) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL
FOLLOWUP_EMAIL FOR COLUMN FOLLO00002 VARCHAR(300) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL
```

print lines containing "table" and its associated "CCSID" if present within () in the paragraphs below.

Comment: Please edit your question to include example output.

Comment: What determines the output? Please make *some* effort to clarify what it is you are asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be more than one way to do this, but I would:

1. Use tr to remove all new lines, making the whole file one long line.
2. Replace ; with ;\n which puts 1 line per query
3. Grep for the query(s) you are trying to find
4. reformat results as desired

Here's a one liner that should work:

```
cat filename|tr -d '\n'|sed -e 's/;/;\n/g'|grep CCSID|sed -e 's/,/,\n/g'
```

To only include the create table and CCSID columns in your output:

```
cat filename|tr -d '\n'|sed -e 's/;/;\n/g'|grep CCSID|sed -e 's/,/,\n/g'|grep "CCSID\|CREATE TABLE"
```

Correction, with the second command you'll end up with misformatted lines, here's an updated one(kinda long, but I tested it against the data you provided mixed with modified data with DDSID which was filtered out):

```
cat testfile|tr -d '\n'|sed -e 's/;/;\n/g'|grep CCSID|sed -e 's/,/,\n/g'|grep "CCSID\|CREATE TABLE"|tr -d '\n'|sed -e 's/CREATE TABLE/;CREATE TABLE/g'|sed -e 's/,$/);/g'|sed -e 's/^;//g'|sed -e 's/,;/);/g'|sed -e 's/;/;\n/g'|sed -e 's/,/,\n/g'
```